# A type of continuous time Markov process

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I am looking for a stochastic process model with the following features.

1. It is a continuous time Markov process---modelling, if you like, the evolution of a population.
2. New arrivals are added to the population at, say, Poisson rate.
3. The existing population following a continuous time Markov process with finite state space, e.g. $\{state1, state2, exit\}$. The holding times in each non-$exit$ state may be Poisson. Once a member of the population hits $exit$, he leaves the population.
4. The Markov transition matrix for existing population is time-invariant. (Pointers to generalization welcome but I would assume relaxing this would make statistical estimation very tricky.)

From perusing the literature, it seems basic models from queueing theory has some similarity with, but not quite the above. For what I am looking for, a new arrival in the queue is Markov jumping between different stations until he hits the "terminal station" and exits the queue.

I would like to also statistically estimate such a model, so parametric assumptions are OK in lieu of generality.

Comment: This needs more thought about the rules of transition. To begin: Can the stations be visited in either order? If both stations are busy can someone enter? What happens to a customer who has finished with one station, but the other is not yet free? Are the rates of service the same at the two stations?

Comment: For the existing population, it's a continuous time Markov chain with no restrictions---except the distinguished "exit" state. For example, there's no such thing as capacity constraint for each state. Holding time---"rates of service"---can be differ across states.

Comment: Your model is related to a cohort model described in Section 2 of [this handout](http://www.win.tue.nl/~resing/2DD50/SOR/handout.pdf).